# Connect UI element click to ViewModel method?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

With [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions) I can create a button an cause it to fire a method in my ViewModel without actually declaring any ICommand properties.

MyView.xaml

```
<UserControl [...]>
    <Button x:Name="Foo" />
</UserControl>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Without using code-behind -- can I do something similar with, say, a Grid? Or any other UI element?
I.e. make it so that when a specific UI element is clicked, a method on the ViewModel is executed, without having to declare any ICommand properties?

I've tried a syntax like this, but nothing seemed to happen.

```
<UserControl [...]>
    <Border cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Foo()]">
        <TextBlock Text="Click Me" />
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You can use `Message.Attach` for that, have a look at [cheat sheet](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/cheat-sheet)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i've tried that, but i might've gotten something wrong. can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: Well, I don't think that `Border` can have any routed events

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i'm afraid i'm very new to WPF and especially to Caliburn.Micro and i'm not really sure what that means. should i use something other than border, or is this an x/y problem?

Comment: should i keep the button and use a `ControlTemplate` to make it look like the other thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Border` doesn't have any `Click` event but you could handle its `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
<Border cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown] = [Action Foo()]">
    <TextBlock Text="Click Me" />
</Border>
```

Comment: thank you! i ended up using `MouseUp` instead because that seems closer to what a button does.

Comment: after seeing this answer i found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement?view=netcore-3.1#events), which lists the events that are supported by all UI elements.